# Comparing multiple object attributes in an arraylist of objects

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I need help coming up with an if-else condition statement to compare multiple object attributes in an arraylist of objects.

For example, say I have an arraylist of appointments

```java
ArrayList<Appointment> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new Appointment(1,101,new Date(),"9 AM - 10 AM"),
        new Appointment(2,200,new Date(),"9 AM - 10 Am"),
        new Appointment(3,200,new Date(),"11 AM - 1 PM")
));
```

This is the `Appointment` class:

```java
public class Appointment {

    private long id;
    private long doctorLicenseNo;
    private Date date;
    private String time;

//constructor + getters and setters

}
```

I want to check if a doctor with a particular license number is booked on a specific date and time. Here the doctor license number, date and time are given.

Comment: "it seems to be giving me some error" could you add the error ?

Comment: a `java.util.Date` is a lie; it does not represent a date at all (it represents an instant in time, which is particularly problematic, given that the 'date' at which some instant in time occurs, is not an answerable question unless you add a timezone into the mix). The correct data type is `LocalDateTime`, or possibly `ZonedDateTime`, which replaces both `String time;` and `Date date;`. Separate from that, as jhamon said, we can't answer your specific issue unless you include the error.

Comment: Unrelated but, regarding your cases, is it necessay to check the appointment time if you already know the date is different (case 3 and 4)?
And don't forget to update the label in case the doctor has no appointment at all.
Also, you are settting the valuie of the label for **each** iteration of the loop which could get you a wrong result in the end

Comment: Another point of view it looks like youre i..else statements gives the same result even the first. So in the first else statement you need only check licenceNo. .. and what if licenceNo does not equals?

Comment: Please try to solve your homework problem on your own first, and include these attempts in your question. As is, it looks a lot like you expect us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, I suppose you find it not working because the for-loop is erasing the label each time.

Also, this code is overly complicated. You can do something like:

```
boolean isDoctorBooked = list.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getDoctorLicenseNo() == licenseNo)
    .anyMatch(a -> a.getDateTime() == dateTime);
```

Assuming you replaced the date and time with the proper object, as per @rzwitserloot comment.